# How to prove the elementary inequality?

Tags: analysis

The inequality is the following:
$$\frac{(1+x)^q-1}{x+x^q} \leq C(q),$$
where $q\in [1,+\infty)$  and $x > 0$, and the constant $C$ depends only on $q$. It's very nice if someone can provide the minimal value of $C(q)$, I guess the minimal value is $q$.

Comment: So the RHS does not depend on $x$ but the inequality holds for all $x$. It means that you have to take $C_q$ as the global maximum of $\dfrac{(1+x)^q-1}{x+x^q}$

Comment: You are right , this inequality means to find the maximum of the function, but how to find the maximum?

Comment: I try to find the critical point of $\frac{(1+x)^q-1}{x+x^q}$ by Maple ,but it failed .

Comment: You need to calculate the derivative and find its roots.

Comment: For what it's worth, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize+%28%281+%2B+q%29%5Ex+-+1%29%2F%28q+%2B+q%5Ex%29+where+x+%3E%3D+1) is unable to find a global maximum.  What have you tried?

Comment: There is none. There is only a supremum.

Answer (score 3):

We will  show that for fixed $q$ the function $\frac{(1+x)^q-1}{x^q+x}$ is bounded. By L'Hospitals Rule, we have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(1+x)^q-1}{x^q+x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{q(1+x)^{q-1}}{qx^{q-1}+1}=q.$$

And it is clear that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(1+x)^q-1}{x^q+x}=1$$
if $q\gt 1$. (The case $q=1$ is easy to deal with.)

Boundedness follows.

Comment: Now the next question (of course), is if

$$f(x,q) = \frac{(1 + x)^q - 1}{x^q + x}$$

is decreasing with respect to $x$.

Comment: @André Nicolas. For sure, I totally agree with your analysis. Do you think that it could be possible to find the upper bound of $C(q)$ ? For integer values of $q\geq 3$, the slope at the origin seems to be $q(q-1)/2$. So, the function starts from $q$, goes to a maximum and decreases to $0$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Interesting. Maybe I can think of something simple. But certainly not now, it is the middle of the night. The question has received insufficient attention.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. So, have a good night ! I hope and wish my question will not generate nightmares ! Cheers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. I made a few little things ! I should really appreciate your opinion. Cheers.

Comment: @ArnieDris. Your short comment made me working much more than I was expecting. Thank you for the entertainment !

Comment: No problem, @ClaudeLeibovici!  In our native dialect:  "Maliit na bagay..."  =)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.

For the function $$F(x,q) = \frac{(1 + x)^q - 1}{x^q + x}$$ André Nicolas showed that $$F(0,q)=q$$ $$F(\infty,q)=1^{+}$$ What I looked at is the problem of the derivative and here, there are a few things which are interesting as soon as $q\gt 2$.

The derivative  $$F'(0,q)=\frac 12 q(q-1)\gt 1$$ means that the function goes through a maximum value. On the other hand $$F'(1,q)=\frac{1}{4} \left(q-2^q+1\right)<0$$ means that the minimum is between $0$ and $1$. So, the value of the function at the maximum is always larger than $$F(1,q)=\frac{1}{2} \left(2^q-1\right)$$ Expanding the function as a Taylor series around $x=1$ shows that the derivative cancels close to $$x^*=\frac{4+8 q+2^q (q^2-3q-4) }{2+6q+2^q \left(q^2-3 q-2\right)}$$ which clearly shows the asymptotic behavior of the location of the maximum.

What it seems (I have not been able to prove it) is that the maximum value of the function is something like $$F(x^*,q)\approx 2^{q-1}(1+\epsilon)$$ and more precisly, $$F(x^*,q)\approx \frac{1}{2} \left(2^q-1+\frac{\left(2^q-q-1\right)^2}{2+6 q+2^q (q^2-3 q-2)}\right)$$

All the above was checked numerically. For example,

- for $q=10$, the maximum is located at $0.972364$ while the approximation gives $\approx 0.970930$; the function value at the maximum is $515.050$ while the approximation gives $518.862$
- for $q=30$, the maximum is located at $0.997536$ while the approximation gives $\approx 0.997525$; the function value at the maximum is $5.37202\times 10^8$ while the approximation gives $5.37535\times 10^8$

Interesting problem, indeed !

Comment: This is very much an answer, a very good answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Be sure I appreciate this coming from you.

Answer (score 1):

*André Nicolas* showed that $C(q)$ is finite and $\ge q$.
*Claude Leibovici* showed that $C(q)\ge \frac12(2^{q}-1)$ and conjectured that $C(q)\approx 2^{q-1}(1+\epsilon)$.
We are still missing an explicit bound on $C(q)$ from above; here's a very simple one:

By the extended mean value theorem with $f(x)=(1+x)^q$ and $g(x)=x+x^q$ we find that
$$ F(x,q)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}=\frac{q(1+\xi)^{q-1}}{1+q\xi^{q-1}}$$
with $0<\xi<x$. 
The supremum of the function $G(x,q)=\frac{q(1+x)^{q-1}}{1+qx^{q-1}}$ is easier to handle as 
$$\begin{align}G'(x,q)&=\frac{q(q-1)(1+x)^{q-2}\cdot (1+qx^{q-1})-q(1+x)^{q-1}\cdot q(q-1)x^{q-2}}{(1+qx^{q-1})^2}\\
&=\frac{q(q-1)(1+x)^{q-2}}{(1+qx^{q-1})^2}\cdot(1+qx^{q-2}-(1+x)qx^{q-2})\\
&=\frac{q(q-1)(1+x)^{q-2}}{(1+qx^{q-1})^2}\cdot(1-qx^{q-1}) \end{align}$$
Hence for $q>1$  (note that $G(x,1)=1$) $G'$ has a unique sign change and so $G$ a maximum at $x^*=\sqrt[q-1]{1/q} <1$. Therefore
$$F(x,q)\le G(x^*,q)=\frac q2 (1+x^*)^{q-1}<q2^{q-1}$$
(Asymptotically, this can be improved to $G(x^*,q)\sim \sqrt q\,2^{q-1}$, which is still larger than the conjectured value, therefore I don't go into that detail)